# Proper use of re.split()?

Tags: python-3.x, string, split

If I understand correctly, `re.split()` can be used to split a string at several different separator characters simultaneously. However, the [function description](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) employs some special characters which I do not understand.

How should I be using `re.split()` properly to split a string at the characters

```
[' ','/']
```

So that, e.g., the string

```
'abc de/fg'
```

becomes split into

```
['abc','de','fg']
```

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the multiple delimiters as the first parameter, separated by a `|`

```
string='abc de/fg'
re.split(' |/',string)
['abc', 'de', 'fg']
```

Another example :

```
string="abc;def!ghi"
re.split(';|!',string)
['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
```

**EDIT :**

If `|` is the delimiter, use the escape character.

```
string="abc|def"
re.split('\|',string)
['abc', 'def']
```

With multiple :

```
string="abc|def;ghi"
re.split('\||;',string)
['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
```

Comment: Thank you! I see, so the `|` acts as an operator and cannot be used as a separator character itself? That is curious.